# Pygame, my sprite looks wierd

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I'm working on this project for Literature class and I'm planning on making a game with pygame based of this book we were reading.

Here's the code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

FPS = 30 
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Animation')

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
romeo = pygame.image.load('rome.png.png')
romeo = pygame.transform.scale(romeo, (50, 50))
romeox = 10
romeoy = 10 

while True: # the main game loop
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_RIGHT]:
        romeox += 5
    if keys[K_LEFT]:
        romeox -= 5
    if keys[K_UP]:
        romeoy -=5
    if keys[K_DOWN]:
        romeoy += 5
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(romeo, (romeox, romeoy))
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Unfortunately, the sprite seems to leave a trail of it's own copies while it moves.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd836.png)

Please help!

Comment: This has been answered here I believe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24843798

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you forgot to clear the screen every iteration

```
# Fill surface with black color
DISPLAYSURF.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

Insert it above the line that blits the sprite onto the screen.

Comment: Thanks, that helped alot

Comment: @SakibPathen You can press the checkmark underneath the upvote arrow to mark the question as answered.